# Convert from JavaScript function to Java for HTTP Post Request

Tags: javascript, java, android, http

I have a somewhat unusual situation: I plan on creating an Android application that needs access to some planet distance calculations, which I found on this following site:

https://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/1224746378

However, I need a way to send this information from my Android application as a POST request and receive back the information. I only need the "Distance(AU)" part of this and the planet's name. So I don't want to use the web page for this, I want to have my own request and then parse the received data and extract the relevant information from it.

Looking at the website's code, I see that when you press the "Execute" button, it goes into the following function:

```
function checkText(){
  if('' != ''){return false;}
  if(document.calc.var_λo.type != 'hidden'){var chkinp=cutcomma(document.calc.var_λo.name ); if(chkinp == null || chkinp == false){document.calc.var_λo.focus();return false;}}
  if(document.calc.var_φ.type != 'hidden'){var chkinp=cutcomma(document.calc.var_φ.name ); if(chkinp == null || chkinp == false){document.calc.var_φ.focus();return false;}}
  if(document.calc.var_Y.type != 'hidden'){var chkinp=cutcomma(document.calc.var_Y.name ); if(chkinp == null || chkinp == false){document.calc.var_Y.focus();return false;}}
  if(document.calc.var_H.type != 'hidden'){var chkinp=cutcomma(document.calc.var_H.name ); if(chkinp == null || chkinp == false){document.calc.var_H.focus();return false;}}
  if(document.calc.var_I.type != 'hidden'){var chkinp=cutcomma(document.calc.var_I.name ); if(chkinp == null || chkinp == false){document.calc.var_I.focus();return false;}}
  libNameSaveCookie();
  uniqueCookieID();
  document.calc.action = '/exec/system/1224746378';
  document.calc.target = '_self';
  document.calc.method = 'post';
  document.calc.submit();
  return true;
}
```

My question is - how can I interpret the above code block so that I can create a Java-based POST request? How can I determine how the request should look like (headers, body) based on the code above? If I can determine that, then I can make my own fields and pretend the request originated on the website, while actually receiving the data in my Android application (I should get an HTML in the response body which should include my results).

Is this crazy talk or can it be done?

PS. I have also contacted the website owners and asked if they have any REST API available, and also requested permission to use the site as described here.

Comment: `if('' != ''){return false;}` for when an empty string changes its value?

Comment: So if they don;t you make a post request from the Java side and than you parse the result to get the info you want out of the page. Basic screen scraping.

Comment: Well, yes, but the question is - how do I do that? How do I arrive at how my request should look like based on the above code?